# Remote Desktop Connection Manager Delete Profile

Tags: remote-desktop, user-profiles

I'm using Windows Remote Desktop Manager 2.7. I have some profile saved as 'Global' profiles. Somehow, today, I have managed to save a 'File' profile, which does not appear in the 'Profile Managment' tab of the 'Default Settings Group Properties', but DOES appear as a profile in all of the server properties.

Searching for a method to remove this profile gives me ways to delete credentials that have been used to log into the specific machine, remove the 'Global' profiles, or simply remove credentials from credential manager, none of which display this 'File' profile.

The only result that comes close to answering the question is [this one](https://www.10it.pl/qa-23-change-remove-credential-remote-desktop-connection-manager/), which specifies removing the credentials from the credentialsProfiles.rdg file where they're stored. However, I cannot find this file on Windows 10 (Even with hidden folders displayed).

How do I deleted a 'File' profile? Alternatively, where in Windows 10 is  credentialsProfiles.rdg stored for RDCMan?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can open the *.rdg file in any text editor and delete everything between the first "credentialsProfiles" til the end delimiter "/credentialsProfiles"

```
<credentialsProfiles>
  <credentialsProfile inherit="None">
        <profileName scope="Local">*ExampleDomain*\*ExampleUser*</profileName>
        <userName>*ExampleUser*</userName>
        <password>*ExamplePass*</password>
        <domain>*ExampleDomain*</domain>
  </credentialsProfile>
  <credentialsProfile inherit="None">
    ...
  </credentialsProfile>
</credentialsProfiles>
```

Delete any `credentialsProfile` blocks and the final format will be:

```
<credentialsProfiles />
```

at the beginning of the file.

It is required by RDCMan 2.7 that it has the "credentialsProfiles" section at the start of the *.RDG file.

Comment: This worked. PS: you won't be able to see your changes in .rdg file until you close and save your changes (at least that was the case for me)

Comment: this is not the best answer, make profile changes in the application itself, see answer below

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to edit the xml file.  You can make all profile changes within the application as follows.

1. Open the Remote Desktop Connection Manager.
2. Right-click the top-most entry in the tree above all groups and servers. (FYI, this will also be the filename of the xml ".rdg" file you're using.)
3. Select "Properties".
4. Click on the "Profile Management" tab.

Here you'll see all the "File" profiles which are saved in the file itself.  You can Add, Edit, and Delete them as needed here.

In contrast, the "Global" profiles are saved in your Windows user profile.  These can be edited through *Tools > Options > General *tab* > Default group settings > Profile Management* tab.

Answer (score 2):

*"File scope is broader and profiles with this scope can be used in the whole .rdg file. They are referenced by name, with the profile definition stored inside the credentialsProfiles tag at the beginning of the .rdg file."*

https://lowleveldesign.org/2016/05/23/incorrect-password-in-remote-desktop-connections-manager-with-some-dpapi-insights/

While this is what you mentioned above I don't believe there is any way around your issue unless you remember where you housed the .RDG file originally.